# SyntaxError: invalid syntax when i import avro in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, avro

I just want to import avro in python3. And I get error just import avro schema.

```
import os
import string
import sys

from avro import schema
...
# others are not matter
```

And I can only read

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ktz/IdeaProjects/HadoopExample/src/main/python/chap4/writer_pairs.py", line 5, in <module>
    from avro import schema
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 954, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 896, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1139, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1115, in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1096, in _legacy_get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 444, in spec_from_loader
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 533, in spec_from_file_location
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/avro-1.8.1-py3.5.egg/avro/schema.py", line 340
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Sorry for that I`m first in Python..

Comment: Remove the comma in file and write `as` instead (so `except Exception as e:`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to read avro files in python 3.5.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732419/how-to-read-avro-files-in-python-3-5-2)

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732419/how-to-read-avro-files-in-python-3-5-2

Comment: That's strange. It says "avro-1.8.1-py3.5.egg", which would seem to be targeted for Python 3.5, but the error message is pointing to Python 2-specific syntax. This might be a library bug.

Comment: @ppasler Hm... maybe it could be.. but I`ll remain this for newbie in python just like me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using python2 version of avro code in python3. if you run the same using python2 then there won't be the error otherwise install python3 compatible avro.

Comment: You're right! Really I appreciate for your kindness.. It`s very helpful for me!! @Harry

Comment: glad to be helpful.

Comment: [This is outdated now](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2676) for folks using a up-to-date avro and Python 3.

Answer (score 22):

you need to use the package avro-python3 instead of avro if you're using Python3

Comment: [This is outdated now](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2676) for folks using a up-to-date avro and Python 3.